# не передаются куки в заголовке запроса, node, react

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, cookie, cors

Есть сервер на express, фронт на react на другом домене. Есть авторизованные запросы, токен храню в куках. Столкунулся с проблемой, не передаются куки в хэдере запросов. Использую библиотеку cors `

```
app.use(cors({
  origin: 'домен',
  credentials: true,
}));`
```

запросы

```
fetch getUserInfo() {
    return fetch(`${this._url}users/me, {
      credentials: 'include',
    })

      .then(this._checkResponse)

  }
```

Если с постмана отправлять запросы то в хэдере запроса лежат куки, если с фронта то нет. А теперь самое странное, у одного человека мой сайт норм работает, куки в запросе отправляются, с чем связанно не понимаю.

Answer (score 0):

Решил проблему проставив при создании кук secure: true, sameSite: none

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]